# PHP copy + overwrite dialog per file

Tags: php, ajax, file, directory, copy

I'm developing a system in PHP + AJAX that could copy files from one folder on the server to another folder in the server.

My question is when I try to copy a folder to another one that already have some files with the same name inside of it.

In this case, I want to show a popup to the user in order to confirm if he wants to overwrite EACH one of this files.

How could I do that? How can I wait for the response of the user to each dialog after starting the copy?

By the way, is it better to use the `cp` command of linux or is it better to do this using `unlink` and `rmdir` of PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should divide the process into several parts:

1. Check for colliding files.
2. If some colliding files exist, list them to the user and ask for
   confirmation (dialog).
3. If there's no collision, or if the user confirm he agrees to
   overwrite destination files, copy the files.

If you want to ask for each one of this files, ask a confirmation per file (a dialog box with checkboxes, or several dialog boxes). Once the user has confirm (or not) every overwriting, copy the files.

Comment: So, if I want to show one dialog per file, I need to pass on POST or GET something that says that the user as already answered for the overwrite question of that file right?

Comment: I think I would pass only one POST request at the end of the confirmation step, with a list of files to overwrite (or files to keep).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the copy() function to copy files from one folder to another

```
$sourceFilePath = '/path/to/source/file.jpg';
$destinationFilePath = '/path/to/destination/file.jpg';
if (copy($sourceFilePath, $destinationFilePath)) {
    // File copied successfully
} else {
    // Error occurred during file copy
}
```

Next, you can add a AJAX confirmation dialog to prompt the user for each file that already exists in the destination folder.

```
function copyFile(source, destination) {
    // Send an AJAX request to copy the file
    $.ajax({
        url: 'copy_file.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            source: source,
            destination: destination
        },
        success: function(response) {
            if (response === 'overwrite') {
                // Display a confirmation dialog
                if (confirm('A file with the same name already exists. Do you want to overwrite it?')) {
                    // User confirmed, proceed with the copy
                    copyFile(source, destination + '&overwrite=true');
                } else {
                    // User canceled, do not overwrite
                    // Handle accordingly
                }
            } else {
                // File copied successfully or other response handling
                // Handle accordingly
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            // Error handling
            // Handle accordingly
        }
    });
}
```

In your PHP script (copy_file.php), you can handle the copy process and check if the destination file already exists and send a response back.

```
$sourceFilePath = $_POST['source'];
$destinationFilePath = $_POST['destination'];

if (file_exists($destinationFilePath)) {
    // File already exists, send overwrite response
    echo 'overwrite';
} else {
    // Copy the file
    if (copy($sourceFilePath, $destinationFilePath)) {
        // File copied successfully
        echo 'success';
    } else {
        // Error occurred during file copy
        echo 'error';
    }
}
```